# How to fix zsh: permission denied when running Gradle commands on Android Studio Terminal on MacOS

Tags: android

I can not run any *Gradle* command (for example `./gradlew build`) on *Android Studio Terminal*. Every time I get `zsh: permission denied`.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you get `zsh: permission denied` you need to run `chmod 755 gradlew` first and you'll get rid of the error.

Answer (score 6):

If you get

```
zsh: operation not permitted: ./gradlew
```

and you are using MacOS Venture+ then use:

```
sudo bash ./gradlew ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to set the execution flag on your gradlew file:

chmod +x gradlew

Answer (score 2):

You can solve that using this command on terminal.

```
sudo chmod +x ./gradlew
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions worked for me.

I was facing the same issue in React Native 0.69.0. Replacing the gradlew file with the newly cloned project resolve my issue.

The issue is in the gradlew file in my case it was a corrupt file.